# Azure incorrect number of disks

Tags: azure

I have a Virtual machine at Azure with 8 disks. However, Disk Manager is showing only 7 disks.

Also, this status message is displayed in Azure Dashboard "Stopped! Virtual machines continue to incur compute charges even when they are stopped You can avoid these charges by deleting the virtual machine". However, the VM is running perfectly.

Any clues?

Thanks,
Rune

Comment: Are you sure you're connection to the same VM? Do you have multiple VMs which are load balanced? Did you try CTRL+F5 in the management portal?

Comment: Yes, am sure. I added 4 new disks to the total of 8 disks in Azure Dashboard, but only 3 new disks appeared in Disk Manager. I dont have any load balancing.

Comment: Maybe one disk attachment failed - can you try adding it again?

Comment: When I click Start in Azure dashboard. I get the message "The operation cannot be performed because the virtual machine is faulted". Ok, I will try adding the disks again.

Comment: Looks like your VM may have some issues - you might want to reimage it.

Comment: I have detached all the drives in Azure Dashboard. It is not in faulted state anymore, but the disks are still visible in Disk Management. How do I remove the disks on the VM?

Comment: Is it possible in Disk Managment to see the name of the azure disk?

Comment: Select your VM, go to Dashboard tab and there is a section `disks` at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

The number of supported data disks varies with the VM size.  Have you reached the limit for your VM?

XS: 1, S: 2, M: 4, L: 8, XL: 16, A6: 8, A7: 16

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn197896.aspx